TypeScript infers wrong type for AbstractControl with generic type
I have an InnerComponent that takes a FormArray as input. The component needs access to the type of the controls in the array. Hence I introduce a type parameter ControlValue and declare that the input must be of the type FormArray<AbstractControl<ControlValue>>. I’m using the AbstractControl rather than FormControl because it’s fine for the component if the values in the array are structured in any way.
export class InnerComponent<ControlValue> {
  @Input({ required: true }) public formArray!: FormArray<AbstractControl<ControlValue>>
}

When I try to assign a value of type FormArray<FormControl<number | null>> to the formArray in InnerComponent, I expect TypeScript to resolve the type parameter ControlValue to the type number | null.
What I actually get is this compile error:
Type
  FormArray<
    FormControl<number | null>
  >
is not assignable to type
  FormArray<
    AbstractControl<
      number | FormControlState<number | null> | null,
      number | FormControlState<number | null> | null
    >
  >

The compiler expects a wider type for the FormControls than I intended, namely number | FormControlState<number | null> | null instead of number | null. Why is that?
The components compile fine if I use FormControl instead of AbstractControl, but I don’t like to force the FormArray to be ‘flat’. It also infers the correct type if I pull out the ControlValue type like this:
export class InnerComponent<ControlValue, C extends AbstractControl<ControlValue>> {
  @Input({ required: true }) public formArray!: FormArray<C>
}

I’m not fond of this solution because the type of a single control in the InnerComponent is then inferred as
AbstractControl<any, any> | C, which requires type casts if I need it to be of type C only.
Full code (paste it in https://angular.dev/playground):
import {Component, Input} from '@angular/core';
import {FormArray, AbstractControl, FormControl} from '@angular/forms';
import {bootstrapApplication} from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Component({
  selector: 'inner',
  template: '',
  standalone: true
})
export class InnerComponent<ControlValue> {
  @Input({ required: true }) public formArray!: FormArray<AbstractControl<ControlValue>>
}

@Component({
  imports: [InnerComponent],
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  template: `
    <inner [formArray]="formArray"></inner>
  `,
})
export class PlaygroundComponent {
  public formArray!: FormArray<FormControl<number | null>>
}

bootstrapApplication(PlaygroundComponent);


You can use the below type <ControlValue extends AbstractControl<any>>
import {Component, Input} from '@angular/core';
import {FormArray, AbstractControl, FormControl} from '@angular/forms';
import {bootstrapApplication} from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Component({
  selector: 'inner',
  template: 'asdasd',
  standalone: true
})
export class InnerComponent<ControlValue extends AbstractControl<any>> {
  @Input({ required: true }) public formArray!: FormArray<ControlValue>
}

@Component({
  imports: [InnerComponent],
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  template: `
    <inner [formArray]="formArray"></inner>
  `,
})
export class PlaygroundComponent {
  public formArray!: FormArray<FormControl<number | null>>
}

bootstrapApplication(PlaygroundComponent);


Just change the AbstractControl to FormControl.
FormControl inherits AbstractControl, to me it makes logic to use the wider type since it already contains AbstractControl and this will solve your issue!
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import 'zone.js';
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';
import {
  FormArray,
  AbstractControl,
  FormControl,
  FormsModule,
  ReactiveFormsModule,
} from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'inner',
  template: 'inner',
  standalone: true,
})
export class InnerComponent<ControlValue> {
  @Input({ required: true }) public formArray!: FormArray<
    FormControl<ControlValue>
  >;
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [InnerComponent, ReactiveFormsModule],
  template: `
    <inner [formArray]="formArray"></inner>
  `,
})
export class App {
  public formArray!: FormArray<FormControl<number | null>>;
  name = 'Angular';
}

bootstrapApplication(App);

Stackblitz Demo

As I wrote in the question: I don’t like to force the FormArray to be ‘flat’. Your solution prevents App::formArray to contain FormGroups instead of FormControls.

@bleistift2 then why don't you do public formArray!: FormArray<AbstractControl<number | null>>;

If you suggest changing the type of InnerComponent::formArray to FormArray<AbstractControl<number | null>>: That’s impossible. ControlValue needs to be generic, since the component needs to handle different types passed from the outer component. If you suggest that App::formArray should have the type FormArray<AbstractControl<number | null>>: That would mean throwing away the concrete type information in the App class, which would require type casts whenever the App needs to do something with the controls in the array – for instance, adding a formGroup to the array.

@bleistift2 FormGroup inherits AbstractControl, FormControl inherits AbstractControl, so How can typescript figure out whether its a form group or control, all it can know is its a AbstractControl, so we can just pass it in as a abstract control, because FormGroup (Large) and FormControl(Large) cannot fit inside AbstractControl (Small). but small can fit inside large, hope my point is understood!

@bleistift2 You can just do export class InnerComponent<ControlValue extends AbstractControl<any>> { this will give you the methods, but there is not a way to preserve the type!
